# How to completely free a timer(timer_list)?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, embedded, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am working on an application with multiple timers. When the application starts, everything is just runs as standard, except I have some pointers point to the timer.

I will show a piece of sample code to clarify my purpose:

---------------------------init foo---------------------

```
init_timer(&timer1);//timer1 definition is outside the function, as struct timer_list timer1
timer1.expires = jiffies+SECONDS_TO_JIFFIES(5);
timer1.data = (unsigned long) data;
timer1.function = callback_foo;
timer1_pointer = &timer1;//timer1_pointer definition is outside the function, as struct timer_list *timer1_pointer
```

------------------the other function after init---------------

```
add_timer(timer1_pointer);
```

-------------------deinit---------------------------

```
del_timer_sync(&timer1);
```

It works fine in the beginning, however it will always crash at add_timer when the whole flow (deinit->init->the other function->...) runs again.

It makes me feel something is wrong in the deinit. Since delete timer only detach instead of delete. Rerun the flow may mesh up the timer list.

So are there any ways to safely free it? Or if you find any other mistakes I made?

Comment: Step through the code with the debugger.  Find where it crashes and examine the variable and register values to understand why it's crashing.  We can't give you more specific suggestions without knowing more about your system and code.  At least show the source for `add_timer` and `del_timer_sync`.

Comment: Is there any shared resource which you are dealing within timer callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

OK，since no one answered, I just post some thoughts and I finally proved it truly the reason that trigger the crash.

It seems that, if the timer are required to be relaunched and deleted sometimes during a long run application, it is necessary to free/clean the timer_list. This del_timer_sync/del_timer not really *delete* it as I thought. Since the project I am working on is complicated, I guess some dude just make things messy and affect me..I will try to dig it later if I have time.